# WCF tracing & message logging - trace level warning

Tags: wcf, logging, message, trace

Assume I have a config file which looks like this:
     
      ...

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add initializeData="LogServer.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

When using this config file every activity the caller performs against the service and each corresponding message that's sent to the service will be logged in the svclog file. Everything fine so far.

If I modify the 3rd line from the above listing to `<source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" propagateActivity="true">` (the `ActivityTracing` is removed) then only those activities are logged that are at least labeled level warning. But it's still every message logged...

So is there a way to only log those message that correspond to those activities that are at least warnings? Those messages that succeeded aren't very interesting in that moment, but those messages that belong to the unsuccessful activities are!

Comment: Try setting the switchValue="Warning" on <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">

Comment: Did you resolve this yourself? It is my question as well....

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
To filter messages beyond the options below you may want to look into writing your own TraceSource.

Below is one I am using for a project.  You could easily customize it to filter out the messages you want or perhaps hide activity if it is not in DEBUG, etc.

```
class DB : TraceSource
{
    public DB(string name) : base(name)
    { 
    }

    public DB(string name, SourceLevels sourceLevels) : base (name, sourceLevels)
    { 
    } 

    public void Log(object value)
    {
        WriteLine(value);
    }

    public void Error(object value)
    {
        WriteLine(value, TraceEventType.Error);
    }

    public void Error(RecordingResponseData errorResponse)
    {
        string errorMessage = "[Error] Code: "+errorResponse.ErrorCode +" Message: "+errorResponse.ErrorMessage;
        WriteLine(errorMessage, TraceEventType.Error);
    }

    public void Warn(object value)
    {
        WriteLine(value, TraceEventType.Warning);
    }

    public void WriteLine(object value, TraceEventType type = TraceEventType.Information)
    { 
        TraceEvent(type, 0, value.ToString());
    }


}
```

**Original**

Your options are:

1. Critical
2. Error
3. Warning
4. Information
5. ActivityTracing
6. Verbose
7. All

Or a combination there of.  If you have it set to Warning but are still getting too many messages then you may want to try Error or Critical.

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That's still not what I was looking for ;-) The problem wasn't the amount of _activities_ logged. These were perfectly filtered to warning and above. What I was looking for was a way to filter the _messages_ (!= activities), too.

Comment: There are search boxes and filters within 'Microsoft Service Trace Viewer' that can filter within the messages.

Comment: Otherwise you could extend TraceSource and override the WriteLine method.  Let me update my answer to show how that may work for you.

Comment: That's a nice idea! Although I think, that I would have to extend `TraceListener` (or more specific in my case [`XmlWriterTraceListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener.aspx)) instead of `TraceSource` as I think the tracesources I'm bound to (`System.ServiceModel`, `System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging`) are given whereas I'm free in using a (custom) listener that I want. Insofar this looks like a good idea, although it requires rolling a custom class for that purpose which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `switchValue` available for the `System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging` trace switch as well. Just add that attribe to that `source` element and set it to `Warning` also and you will only see messages logged that are related to warnings.

Comment: well there is that `switchValue` but it seems to have no effect. When I set it to `Warning` there's still every message logged. Moreover I think this won't - if working - have the effect I want. I think this will cause that only warning-messages (e.g. the warning that the message wasn't logged, because it's to big) are logged, and that's not what I want. I'd like to have those messages logged, that are directly related to an at-least-warning-activity.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging source to get rid of logging messages to resolve "still every message logged".

Comment: That's not what I've been looking for. I wanted to get messages, but not all. Just those that correspond to a warning.